# could not open service xx,when i install a wdf driver to win7 x64

Tags: usb, driver, wdk, inf, kmdf

I think there's a problem in my inf file. But my driver and inf work fine in windows xp and win7 x86.

I also searched this problem, see somebody said service's name not the same. But in my inf, it's the same: `ECTEKCANcard`

My problem is (I get these from windbg):

```
==================

WdfCoInstaller: [04/17/2013 10:37.55.323] DIF_INSTALLDEVICE: Pre-Processing

WdfCoInstaller: [04/17/2013 10:37.55.385] ReadComponents:  WdfSection for Driver Service ECTEKCANcard using KMDF lib version Major 0x1, minor 0x9 

WdfCoInstaller: [04/17/2013 10:37.55.432] DIF_INSTALLDEVICE: Post-Processing

WdfCoInstaller: [04/17/2013 10:37.55.479] BootApplication: could not open service ECTEKCANcard, error error(1060)  The specified service does not exist as an
installed service.

WdfCoInstaller: [04/17/2013 10:37.55.510] BootApplication: GetStartType error error(87) The parameter is incorrect.

 Driver Service name ECTEKCANcard

=======================
```

My inf file:

```
[Version]

Signature="$WINDOWS NT$"

Class=USB   

ClassGuid={36FC9E60-C465-11CF-8056-444553540000}

provider=%PHILIPS%

DriverVer=02/01/2013,1.0.0000.0000

[ControlFlags]

ExcludeFromSelect = *

[SourceDisksNames]

1=%Disk_Description%,,,

[SourceDisksFiles.x86]

CANcard.sys = 1,,

WdfCoInstaller01009.dll=1,,

[SourceDisksFiles.amd64]

CANcard.sys = 1,,

WdfCoInstaller01009.dll=1,,

[DestinationDirs]

DefaultDestDir = 12

CoInstaller.Files = 11

[CANcard.Files]

CANcard.sys

[CoInstaller.Files]

WdfCoInstaller01009.dll

[Manufacturer]

%MfgName%=ECTEKCANcard, NTX86, NtAMD64

[ECTEKCANcard]

%USB\VID_0471&PID_1200.DeviceDesc%=ECTEKCANcard.Dev, USB\VID_0471&PID_1200

[ECTEKCANcard.NTx86]

%USB\VID_0471&PID_1200.DeviceDesc%=ECTEKCANcard.Dev, USB\VID_0471&PID_1200

[ECTEKCANcard.NTAMD64]

%USB\VID_0471&PID_1200.DeviceDesc%=ECTEKCANcard.Dev, USB\VID_0471&PID_1200

[ECTEKCANcard.Dev.NTx86]

CopyFiles=CANcard.Files

[ECTEKCANcard.Dev.NTx86.Services]

Addservice = ECTEKCANcard, 0x00000002, CANcard.AddService

[ECTEKCANcard.Dev.NTx86.HW]

AddReg = ECTEKCANcard.Security

[ECTEKCANcard.Dev.NTAMD64]

CopyFiles=CANcard.Files

[ECTEKCANcard.Dev.NTAMD64.Services]

Addservice = ECTEKCANcard, 0x00000002, CANcard.AddService

[ECTEKCANcard.Dev.NTAMD64.HW]

AddReg = ECTEKCANcard.Security

[CANcard.AddService]

DisplayName    = %CANcard.SvcDesc%

ServiceType    = 1                  ; SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER

StartType      = 3                  ; SERVICE_DEMAND_START

ErrorControl   = 1                  ; SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL

ServiceBinary  = %10%\System32\Drivers\CANcard.sys

LoadOrderGroup = Base

[ECTEKCANcard.Security]

HKR,,DeviceCharacteristics,0x10001,0x100

HKR,,Security,,"D:P(A;;GA;;;SY)(A;;GRGWGX;;;BA)(A;;GRGW;;;WD)(A;;GRGW;;;RC)"

[ECTEKCANcard.Dev.NTAMD64.CoInstallers]

AddReg=CoInstaller_AddReg

CopyFiles=CoInstaller.Files

[ECTEKCANcard.Dev.NTx86.CoInstallers]

AddReg=CoInstaller_AddReg

CopyFiles=CoInstaller.Files

[CoInstaller_AddReg]

HKR,,CoInstallers32,0x00010000, "WdfCoInstaller01009.dll,WdfCoInstaller"

[ECTEKCANcard.Dev.NTAMD64.Wdf]

KmdfService = ECTEKCANcard, CANcard_wdfsect

[ECTEKCANcard.Dev.NTx86.Wdf]

KmdfService = ECTEKCANcard, CANcard_wdfsect

[CANcard_wdfsect]

KmdfLibraryVersion = 1.9

[Strings]

MfgName="ECTEK"

Disk_Description = "CANcard Installation Disk"

CANcard.SvcDesc = "CanCard.sys ectek"

USB\VID_0471&PID_1200.DeviceDesc="ECTEK USBCAN"

PHILIPS="ECTEK Automotive Electronics Co,LTD"
```

Does anybody know?